# Missing parameter id in yii2 model function

Tags: php, yii2

I have these 2 methods for my previous and next records buttons in my task model

```
public function getNext()
{
    return Task::find()
         ->where(['>', 'id', $this->id])
         ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])
         ->one();
}

public function getPrev()
{
    return Task::find()
         ->where(['<', 'id', $this->id])
         ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
         ->one();
}
```

this is working fine but after the last record and before 1 record I get this error Missing required parameters: id.
how can I display a custom message instead of this error or disable/hide the next button when it reaches the last record

code in the view file

```
<?= Html::a('Previous',  
    ['/pmt/task/task-view', 'id' => $model->prev->id], 
    ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs']); 
?>
<?= Html::a('Next',  
    ['/pmt/task/task-view', 'id' => $model->next->id],
    ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs']); 
?>
```

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the request url. Does the call action have a parameter?

Comment: @robsch I added the view file code for the buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put an if statement around the next button?

```
<?= Html::a('Previous',  
  ['/pmt/task/task-view', 'id' => $model->prev->id], 
  ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs']); ?>
<?php if($next = $model->next) {
  <?= Html::a('Next',  
    ['/pmt/task/task-view', 'id' => $next->id], 
    ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs']); ?>
<?php } ?>
```